# EE 2.7.1 - Channel Form for new entry not working

Tags: ee2, safecracker, entries, saef

I have completed the editing of entries with Chanel_Forms, but I can't get channel_forms to create an entry. I am running MSM and have EE 2.7.1. Below is my code. You can see this is extremely basic. What is going wrong here? When I submit, the page just refreshes and does not enter the new entry in EE CP.

```
            {exp:channel:form 
                channel="test_channel" 
                site="blogs" 
                id="newEntryForm" 
                return="{site_url}/inline/URL_TITLE"
            }
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">
                {label:test}
                {field:test}
                <br/><br />

                <input id="submitMe" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            {/exp:channel:form}
```

---

Sorry guys... I bounced off of this project completely. I will rebuild this test environment and make the suggested changes to reply with the results.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

1) Are there any required fields that you didn't add to the form?

2) Does the user you're logged into as (or the guest user you are using) have permissions to post in the channel?

3) Have you tried adding in the URL title field? It's not supposed to be required, but I've had that cause issues before.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeremy's suggestions... Triple check these two parameters

```
channel="test_channel" 
site="blogs"
```

They must match what is set in EE.

---

If you're using a guest user_ID to allow users to post to the channel, you must set the **[logged_out_member_id](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#logged-out-member-id)** parameter on the form tag and that member group must have permissions set to post to the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but I discovered that the form worked when it wasn't in the "home page" template group.

Literally just changing a different template group to the "home page" group magically made the channel form start writing to the database correctly.

It's not a permanent solution, but it may be a workaround.